# I got a TypeError after i tried to implement "Edit" and "Delete" in a JavaScript form

Tags: javascript

I need to make a JavaScript form that allows you to edit or delete stuff that you submitted.
I used this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rNQeJi3Wp4),  but when I tried to implement the edit function, it doesn't create the hyperlink, and when I click on it, it says

> script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
> at editRow (script.js:14)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:1)"

Also I found out that the "selectedRow.cells" returns "undefined".

here is the code:
https://pastebin.com/pZVQ91D0

here is the function:

```
function editRow(td) {
    //document.getElementById("AS").deleteRow(td);
    selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;
    console.log(selectedRow.cells);
    input.value = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
}
```

(The guy in the video solved the whole thing differently. I just tried to implement SOME of his code into my approach.)

Can you help me?

Comment: Please include all relevant code as a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site like pastebin. You can likely use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to do so.

Comment: you are calling the function and passing the form object you obviously need to pass the td object.. `<a onClick="editRow(this)">Edit</a>`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of **selectedRow.cells** is undefined so you are getting that error. The cells should have an some value. If you can add more code it will be helpful.

Comment: Hey, the full code is here: https://codepen.io/xpararush/pen/gOMvVXa

Comment: Hey I am  not sure what you are trying to do in that code. But there is no cells property to that selected row which is why this error. You are trying to fetch the value of undefined